# Selecting Excel rows with data in first column via Linq

Tags: linq, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to select just the rows from an Excel spreadsheet that have data in the first column.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
        IEnumerable<Row> dataRows =
          from row in worksheet.Descendants<Row>()
          where (row.RowIndex > 2 
            && row.Descendants<Cell>().First().CellValue != null)
          select row;
```

When I run this code, the debugger tells me "Error in implicit conversion. Cannot convert null object."

I can't figure out what the null object is.  I assume that each row has a non-null first cell (though, of course, the CellValue of the cell in question may be null).

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: My problem actually appears to be with the RowIndex property.  For some reason, it's null on some of the rows in my spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

If a row or cell is empty, it *can* be `null`. The null object can be coming from a row that doesn't have a value in the first cell (and was never initialized).

So when you run `row.Descendants<Cell>().First().CellValue`, the `null` object is coming from `.First()`, that cell has not yet been initialized.

Try the following:

```
IEnumerable<Row> dataRows =
    from row in templateWorksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Row>()
    where (row.RowIndex > 2 
        && row.Descendants<Cell>().First() != null                        
        && row.Descendants<Cell>().First().CellValue != null)
    select row;
```